# Parsing an Object with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb

I have the following format:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "61f41a529210000060005487" }, "number" : "3", "name" : "Honduras", "description" : "1500m height farming, price per 200gr", "price" : 7, "stock" : 10, "stars" : "Rated with 4.0 stars by users." }
```

I need to parse a few entries like the above in PHP. I am using foreach for that purpose. Everything except {"_id": {"$oid": ... }} field seems to be parsed correctly. I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string
```

PHP script:

```
 $products = json_encode($cursor['products']);
 $products = json_decode($products, true) ;
 foreach ($products as $product) {
      $stringID = (string)$product['_id'];
      echo '<tr>';
           echo '<td>' . $stringID . '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $product['number'] . '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $product['name'] . '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $product['description'] . '</td>'; 
           echo '<td>' . $product['price'] . '</td>'; 
           echo '<td>' . $product['stock'] . '</td>'; 
           echo '<td>' . $product['stars'] . '</td>';
       echo '</tr>';
 }
```

I have tried many solutions can't parse it though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does something like `$stringID = $product['_id']['$oid'];` give you what you are after?

Comment: @NigelRen Unfortunately it doesn't :(

Comment: Actually [not reproductible](https://3v4l.org/4gX0t). You probably missed something in your question. What does `var_dump($product)` prints? I guess `$product` is not an object.

Comment: @Syscall Yes, it prints the following **string(216) "{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "61f41a529210000060005487" }, "number" : "3", "name" : "Honduras", "description" : "1500m height farming, price per 200gr", "price" : 7, "stock" : 10, "stars" : "Rated with 4.0 stars by users." }"** . Variable product is stored in MongoDB as an Array.

Comment: so, it's a string, not an object. You should `json_decode($product)` before to access to properties. `foreach ($products as $product) { $product = json_decode($product); ...`

Comment: You are right! Now it prints values but still $oid is not displayed. **Warning: Attempt to read property "$oid" on array** .

Comment: Thank you **NigelRen** and **Syscall** . Your suggestions worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$product` is a string, not an object. You should `json_decode($product)` before to access to properties.

```
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
    $product = json_decode($product);    // << decode here
    $stringID = $product['_id']['$oid']; // << access to ID

    // echo row :
    echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>' . $stringID . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $product['number'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $product['name'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $product['description'] . '</td>'; 
         echo '<td>' . $product['price'] . '</td>'; 
         echo '<td>' . $product['stock'] . '</td>'; 
         echo '<td>' . $product['stars'] . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}
```